# How to get value of dropped file in file input using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, input

Is it possible to set the data of a dropped file in a file upload input field? Or need a dropped file to be uploaded instantly to the server?

Example code:

```
<input type="file" id="drop-box" />
```

```js
$("#drop-box").on('drop', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();      
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    readURL(files);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('input')[0].files[0]` instead `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files`.

> The drop event is fired when an element or text selection is dropped
>   on a valid drop target.

When you drop file into input, `JQuery` `drop` event fired, while it doesn't select file.
You need to wait few time that file does select.

Run bottom example and drop file on input to see result.

```js
$("#drop-box").on('drop', function (e){
    setTimeout(function(){   
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        var files = $('#drop-box')[0].files[0];
        
        $("p").text(files.name);
        $('#drop-box').val("");
    },1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="drop-box" />
<p></p>
```